# What should I initialize the smallest number with to get the smallest number from the following code without any array?

Tags: python

In the code below I want the loop to run until user enters 'done' I want the minimum number. I initialized smallest with 0 but didn't work well as you can see in output below the code

```
smallest= 0

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    
    if num == "done":
        break

        
    if (int(num)<smallest):
        smallest=int(num)
        
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 100
Enter a number: 15
Enter a number: done
Minimum is 0
```

Now even if I try with smallest=100 and I start to enter number as 101,102,103 then also it will show 100 but I want a general solution.
I hope you can give me the answer and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend initializing to `None`

```py
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    
    if num == "done":
        break

    # force num to be saved to smallest if it's the first one
    if smallest is None or int(num) < smallest:
        smallest = int(num)
        
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Note also that the if-condition lower down has changed to force the first input number to be saved into `smallest`

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to allow any numbers:

```
import math
smallest = math.inf
```

Comment: or just `float('inf')`

Comment: Was about to suggest the same thing but with `numpy.infty`. Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: @wikikikitiki `numpy.inf`, `numpy.inf`, and `math.inf` are all just referring to a `float` object that is equivalent to `float('inf')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think about why you are setting smallest to 0 in the first place.
In your case, setting smallest to 0 at compile time means that 0 is your smallest number up until this point and if the list of numbers you are inputting don't contain numbers <=0 then 0 will always be the smallest even if it is not found in your input.

Try setting smallest to the first number the user enters, then make your comparisons after.

ie.

```
smallest = input("Enter a number: ")

while True:
     num = input("Enter a number: ")
```

etc.

Comment: ```smallest = int(input("Enter a number: "))```  instead of  ```smallest = 0 ```

Comment: I don't think that having the `input(...)` command repeated is the best solution.
Also, this doesn't account for the user entering `done` as their first input.

Answer (score 0):

There is also one thing you can do

```
smallest = 0

a = (input("Enter a number: "))
if a!='done':
  smallest = int(a)

while(a!='done'):
    a = (input("Enter a number: "))
    if a == 'done':
        break
    if int(a) < smallest:
        smallest = int(a)
print("Smallest : ",smallest)
```

You can first input and initialize smallest to that number

Comment: I don't think that having the `input(...)` command repeated is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

smallest = float(‘inf’)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).